# Error Could not load the JavaScript files needed to display output

Tags: google-colaboratory

Oftentimes I encounter on Google Colab. How can I avoid this error?

> Error
>   Could not load the JavaScript files needed to display output.
>   This is probably because your Google Account login access has expired or because third-party cookies are not allowed by your browser.